# How to query xml column in TSQL for specific text

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I am trying to query the word `Simple` out the following XML Document.
The column is `xml` data type, the column name is `InstanceSecurity`.

```
<InstanceSecurity>
  <Folder>
    <Authorization Mode="Simple">
      <Deny PrivilegeCode="Create" />
      <Deny PrivilegeCode="Delete" />
      <Deny PrivilegeCode="Edit" />
      <Deny PrivilegeCode="Read" />
      <Deny PrivilegeCode="View" />
      <Deny PrivilegeCode="Print" />
      <Allow PrivilegeCode="All" EntityType="Personnel" EntityVal="5bc2" />
      <Allow PrivilegeCode="All" EntityType="Personnel" EntityVal="f85b" />
    </Authorization>
  </Folder>
</InstanceSecurity>
```

I've tried:

```
Select InstanceSecurity.query('/InstanceSecurity/Folder/Authorization[@Mode="Simple"]') AS SecuredMode
FROM Cases
```

AND

```
SELECT *
FROM Cases
WHERE InstanceSecurity.value('(/InstanceSecurity/Folder/Authorization/Mode)[1]','nvarchar(100)') like '%'
```

Neither one returns anything

Most examples I have looked at have a start and end tag, like

```
<item id="a">a is for apple</item>
```

not sure if that has any effect on how to query this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very important to understand, what content you want to pick out of an XML. There are **elements** and **attributes** - and the floating **text** between element tags, the `text()` node. Execute this to see the principles:

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<root>
    <AnElement ID="1" AnAttribute="The attribute''s content">The element''s content</AnElement>
    <AnElement ID="2" AnAttribute="Only the attribute" />
    <AnElement ID="3">Text only</AnElement>
    <AnElement ID="4" AnAttribute="nested children">
        <child>This is the child''s content</child>
        <child>One more child</child>
    </AnElement>
    <AnElement ID="5" AnAttribute="nested children">
        This is text 1 within the element
        <child>This is the child''s content</child>
        This is text 2 within the element
        <child>One more child</child>
        This is text 3 within the element
    </AnElement>
</root>';

SELECT elmt.value(N'@ID',N'int') ID
      ,elmt.value(N'@AnAttribute',N'nvarchar(250)') TheAttribute
      ,elmt.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(250)') TheFirstText
      ,elmt.value(N'text()[2]',N'nvarchar(250)') TheSecondText
      ,elmt.value(N'child[2]/text()[1]',N'nvarchar(250)') TheFirstTextWithinChild2
      ,elmt.value(N'.',N'nvarchar(250)') AS FullNodeContent
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/root/AnElement') AS A(elmt);
```

**Hint:** Try to pick just the last one (`value(N'.'),N'nvarchar(250)'`) and send the output to plain text. This includes spaces and line breaks!

The `text()` (there may be more `text()` nodes within one element!) is just another kind of *node*, coming without surrounding tags.

**Your attempts (slightly changed)**

> Select
>   @xml.query('/InstanceSecurity/Folder/Authorization[@Mode="Simple"]')

This returns all `<Authorization>` nodes (xml typed!) where the attribute "Mode" has the content "Simple"

> SELECT
>   @xml.value('(/InstanceSecurity/Folder/Authorization/@Mode)[1]','nvarchar(100)')
>   (You forgot the `@` before "Mode"!)

This returns the value of the attribute. In the case above this is "Simple"

### About your issue

I do not really know what you want, but one of the following should point you the way

--Returns the first value of attribute `@Mode` at the given path

```
SELECT InstanceSecurity.value(N'(/InstanceSecurity/Folder/Authorization/@Mode)[1]',N'nvarchar(250)')
FROM Cases;
```

--If your XML might include more than one `<Authorization>`, this would return all their `@Mode` attributes

```
SELECT auth.value(N'@Mode',N'nvarchar(250)')
FROM Cases
OUTER APPLY InstanceSecurity.nodes(N'/InstanceSecurity/Folder/Authorization') AS A(auth);
```

--This returns - in cases of many - all `<Authorization>` elements where the `@Mode` is "Simple"

```
SELECT auth.query(N'.')
FROM Cases
OUTER APPLY InstanceSecurity.nodes(N'/InstanceSecurity/Folder/Authorization[@Mode="Simple"]') AS A(auth);
```

--And this returns all table's rows where at least one `@Mode` has the value "Simple"

```
SELECT *
FROM Cases
WHERE InstanceSecurity.exist(N'/InstanceSecurity/Folder/Authorization[@Mode="Simple"]')=1
```

**Final hint:** You can replace a literal value within `XQuery` with `sql:variable("@VarName")` or with `sql:column("ColumnName")`.

Comment: Thanks Shnugo, I am just learning XML, and don't have a good sense of all the pieces/parts yet, still reading the book. What my ultimate goal here was to figure out which cases are secured, so that I don't include them in my SSRS reports.  Secured cases have the XML similar to my example above, unsecured cases have the following XML, <InstanceSecurity>
  <Folder>
    <Authorization />
  </Folder>
</InstanceSecurity>, I was able to read for the existence of the deny tag, which tells me the case is secured. but I wanted to read the word Simple and couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM Cases
WHERE InstanceSecurity.value('(/InstanceSecurity/Folder/Authorization/@Mode)[1]','varchar(100)') = 'Simple'
```

Comment: I do not think, that this really is what the OP needs. If this is the correct return, you should rather use `XML.exist()`. Your approach has to shred each and any XML, just to filter most of this away at the end... `.exist()` is optimized for performance...

Comment: @Shnugo I have always quried a particular value from `XML`s and wasn't familiar with such method. Nice to know that, thanks :)