# Performance Issue with cross apply while reading XML nodes for large dataset

Tags: sql, xml, sqlperformance, cross-apply

Performance issue with XML cross apply:

DataTable has 1300 entries and the field **xmldata** has 250 nodes, so the query is running 1300 * 250 times to brings the output and the execution times takes a while.. about an hour to generate 325000 rows. Does anybody face a similar issue with the large dataset? Your help is highly appreciated.

**Sample XML:**

```
<dataModel>
  <Colum1>
    <value />
    <displayText />
    <controltype>textbox</controltype>
    <label>Field1</label>
    <controlid>4458575-b0d3-ff4d-01ac-5447e21234dd</controlid>
  </Colum1>
  <Colum2>
    <value />
    <displayText />
    <controltype>textbox</controltype>
    <label>Field2</label>
    <controlid>5a5b7b7e-7b66-1f0d-a562-9d0660a74e11</controlid>
  </Colum2>
....
</dataModel>

select  t.c.value('(local-name(.))[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as keyname ,
        t.c.value('(controlid)[1]', 'nvarchar(200)') as controlid,
        t.c.value('(label)[1]', 'nvarchar(500)') as label
from DataTable xmldata 
CROSS APPLY xmldata .nodes('/dataModel/*') T(c)
```

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what platform or application you're asking about. Consider revising your question to include more specific details.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems to be pretty straight forward. Not much space for enhancements...

The following is just a tiny change, but might speed up things:

```
declare @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(N'<dataModel>
  <Colum1>
    <value />
    <displayText />
    <controltype>textbox</controltype>
    <label>Field1</label>
    <controlid>4458575-b0d3-ff4d-01ac-5447e21234dd</controlid>
  </Colum1>
  <Colum2>
    <value />
    <displayText />
    <controltype>textbox</controltype>
    <label>Field2</label>
    <controlid>5a5b7b7e-7b66-1f0d-a562-9d0660a74e11</controlid>
  </Colum2>
</dataModel>');

select  t.c.value('(local-name(.))[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as keyname ,
        t.c.value('(controlid/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(200)') as controlid,
        t.c.value('(label/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)') as label
from @tbl xmldata 
CROSS APPLY xmldata .nodes('/dataModel/*') T(c);
```

I added `/text()` to your XPaths (find [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50167165/5089204)).

It would be kind to tell us, how much difference you've encountered using `/text()`, thx.

And important to know: One very expensive part with XML is the initial parsing. Make sure, that the table's column is natively xml typed and that your run-time measurement is not biased by any loading / reading / parsing action (find [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56490763/5089204)).

Comment: Thank you Shnugo, Really appreciated your response.